# Multi Language CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

do you know a plugin for CKEditor to manage multiple locales with one and the same input? Let's say you build a CMS and have a page that can have content. You give it a title and want to provide HTML content in different languages (which will be stored as JSON in a SQL database). Any already existing suggestions for this?

Thanks and best regards.
Bart

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is off-topic for SO. Please read about [what topics can be asked about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It might be on topic at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why is it offtopic? I tagged it with ckeditor because this is a common use case imo!

Comment: The page I linked to states that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic". I have no authority to close your question or anything like that; I'm just letting you know what the official rules are.

Comment: Okay Frank, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I mentioned Software Recommendations earlier; I haven't used it myself, but it sounds like your question is more suited to that site. Perhaps you will get more help there?